# Stock market index replication with entries and exits

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame that contains entries and exits dates of an Index for a number of companies. The DataFrame looks something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'company': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
                   'entry_date': ['2018-01-01', '2018-01-01', '2018-01-02', '2018-01-02'],
                   'exit_date': ['2018-01-05', '2018-01-10', '2018-01-05', '2018-01-06'],
                   'entry_date2': ['2018-01-08', 'NaN', 'NaN', '2018-01-08'],
                   'exit_date2': ['2018-01-09', 'NaN', 'NaN', '2018-01-10']})
```

What I want to create is a new DataFrame that contains every single date in the index and each company as a different column. If a company is part of the index at any date, then a True will appear, otherwise a False. The issue is that, as you can see in the previous DataFrame, some companies enter and exit the index more than once, making it difficult to code. The code I have until now that only works with single entries and exits is the following:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=df['company'].unique(), index=pd.date_range(start=df['entry_date'].min(), end=df['exit_date'].max(), freq='D'))

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    new_df.loc[row['entry_date']:row['exit_date'], row['company']] = True

new_df.fillna(False, inplace=True)
```

This code only works with companies that have only 1 entry and exit date, but not with companies with more than 1 entry and exit date. The output desired would the following:

```
    Date      A      B       C        D
2018-01-01  True    True    False   False
2018-01-02  True    True    True    True
2018-01-03  True    True    True    True
2018-01-04  True    True    True    True
2018-01-05  True    True    True    True
2018-01-06  False   True    False   True
2018-01-07  False   True    False   False
2018-01-08  True    True    False   True
2018-01-09  True    True    False   True
2018-01-10  False   True    False   True
```

Comment: What is the expected output please?

Comment: I just added the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, replacing your `'Nan'` strings by `np.nan`, you can try to find a later date on `exit_date<>`. If it yields an error you can use the current date:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import date

df = pd.DataFrame({'company': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
                   'entry_date': ['2018-01-01', '2018-01-02', '2017-01-03', '2017-01-01', '2018-01-05'],
                   'exit_date': ['2018-05-03', np.nan, '2018-01-05', '2018-05-06', '2018-08-07'],
                   'entry_date2': ['2019-01-01', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, '2018-09-07'],
                   'exit_date2': ['2019-08-01', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]})

#the new_df will look for the latest date on 'exit_date2' now
new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=df['company'].unique(), index=pd.date_range(start=df['entry_date'].dropna().min(), end=df['exit_date2'].dropna().max(), freq='D'))

for i, row in df.iterrows():
      try: #if dropna() encounters a 'NaN' value, it will use the current date
            new_df.loc[row.dropna()['entry_date']:row.dropna()['exit_date'], row['company']] = True           
      except:
            new_df.loc[row.dropna()['entry_date']:date.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), row['company']] = True
      try: #if dropna() encounters a 'NaN' value, it will use the current date
            new_df.loc[row.dropna()['entry_date2']:row.dropna()['exit_date2'], row['company']] = True
      except:
            try: #if dropna() encounters a 'NaN' for the 'entry_date2' it will pass
                  new_df.loc[row.dropna()['entry_date2']:date.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), row['company']] = True
            except:
                  pass
new_df.fillna(False, inplace=True)
```

Output *(notice I changed E's 'entry2_date' to '2018-09-07' so you can see it respects the date gap)*:

```
                A      B      C      D      E
2017-01-01  False  False  False   True  False
2017-01-02  False  False  False   True  False
2017-01-03  False  False   True   True  False
2017-01-04  False  False   True   True  False
2017-01-05  False  False   True   True  False
          ...    ...    ...    ...    ...
2019-07-28   True   True  False  False   True
2019-07-29   True   True  False  False   True
2019-07-30   True   True  False  False   True
2019-07-31   True   True  False  False   True
2019-08-01   True   True  False  False   True

[943 rows x 5 columns]

Displaying max rows:
...
2018-08-04  False   True  False  False   True
2018-08-05  False   True  False  False   True
2018-08-06  False   True  False  False   True
2018-08-07  False   True  False  False   True
2018-08-08  False   True  False  False  False
2018-08-09  False   True  False  False  False
2018-08-10  False   True  False  False  False
2018-08-11  False   True  False  False  False
2018-08-12  False   True  False  False  False
2018-08-13  False   True  False  False  False
2018-08-14  False   True  False  False  False
2018-08-15  False   True  False  False  False
2018-08-16  False   True  False  False  False
2018-08-17  False   True  False  False  False
2018-08-18  False   True  False  False  False
2018-08-19  False   True  False  False  False
2018-08-20  False   True  False  False  False
2018-08-21  False   True  False  False  False
2018-08-22  False   True  False  False  False
2018-08-23  False   True  False  False  False
2018-08-24  False   True  False  False  False
2018-08-25  False   True  False  False  False
2018-08-26  False   True  False  False  False
2018-08-27  False   True  False  False  False
2018-08-28  False   True  False  False  False
2018-08-29  False   True  False  False  False
2018-08-30  False   True  False  False  False
2018-08-31  False   True  False  False  False
2018-09-01  False   True  False  False  False
2018-09-02  False   True  False  False  False
2018-09-03  False   True  False  False  False
2018-09-04  False   True  False  False  False
2018-09-05  False   True  False  False  False
2018-09-06  False   True  False  False  False
2018-09-07  False   True  False  False   True
2018-09-08  False   True  False  False   True
2018-09-09  False   True  False  False   True
2018-09-10  False   True  False  False   True
...
```